# Plotting contour plot of minimum square estimate function in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, contour, mse

To visualize the gradient descent of my linear regression model, I'm trying to do a contour plot for the following `mse` function:

```
import jax.numpy as jnp
import numpy as np

def make_mse(x, t):  
  def mse(w,b): 
    return np.sum(jnp.power(x.dot(w) + b - t, 2))/2
  return mse
```

where the `x` and `y` axes of the plot correspond to `w` and `b` parameters.

The `x` and `t` are non-relevant for the plot, since the values of `x` are just being multiplied by a single value of `w` each time.

I was trying to do the following:

```
x = np.linspace(-1.0,1.0,500)
t = 5*x + 1

xcoord = np.linspace(-10.0,10.0,50)
ycoord = np.linspace(-10.0,10.0,50)
w1,w2 = np.meshgrid(xcoord,ycoord)

Z = make_mse(x, t)(w1,w2)
```

However, I get to obvious error for the dot product:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/jax/_src/lax/lax.py in dot(lhs, rhs, precision, preferred_element_type)
    634   else:
    635     raise TypeError("Incompatible shapes for dot: got {} and {}.".format(
--> 636         lhs.shape, rhs.shape))
    637 
    638 

TypeError: Incompatible shapes for dot: got (1000, 1) and (50, 50).
```

Any pythonic efficient way to make a contour plot of this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `np.sum()` since you want the MSE for each grid point individually, not their sum. Also, the dimension of `x` and the grid must match. The following works:

```
import numpy as np

def make_mse(x, t):  
  def mse(w,b): 
    return np.power(x.dot(w) + b - t, 2)
  return mse 

x = np.linspace(-1.0,1.0,500)
t = 5*x + 1

xcoord = np.linspace(-10.0,10.0,500)
ycoord = np.linspace(-10.0,10.0,500)
w1,w2 = np.meshgrid(xcoord,ycoord)

Z = make_mse(x, t)(w1,w2)
plt.contourf(w1,w2,Z)
```

with the following output contour

[image]